# ls -s uses wrong block size

Tags: ls, disk-usage, disk, stat

Ubuntu linux: **ls -s** disagrees with **du** & **stat** for the **number of blocks** used by a small file.

```
ls -s  ../nc2/.git/logs/refs/heads/ 
total 4

du  ../nc2/.git/logs/refs/heads/ 
8   ../nc2/.git/logs/refs/heads/

stat ../nc2/.git/logs/refs/heads/   
File: ‘../nc2/.git/logs/refs/heads/’   
Size: 4096          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096 ......

sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda
4096
```

ls -s shows the file using 4 blocks. du & size say it uses 8 blocks.

Why is ls -s seemingly wrong? Can it not detect the correct block size? I can make it say the file uses 8 blocks by running 'ls -s --block-size 512'.

This is NOT a size of file vs number of blocks question. All commands above are listing block size not file size.

Edit: More info requested:

```
ls --version 
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.21

type ls  
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'

LS_BLOCK_SIZE=512 ls -s ../nc2/.git/logs/refs/heads/ 
total 8
```

Comment: Need output of `type ls`, `ls --version`, `env | grep -i BLOCK`, `LS_BLOCK_SIZE=512 ls -s ../nc2/.git/logs/refs/heads/`.  And the output of `ls` and `du` for a file rather than a directory.

Comment: In any case, why do you want 512-byte blocks?  On a GNU/Linux system, it's probably easier to let tools use the default value of 1,024-byte blocks per https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html#Block-size.

Comment: ls uses 1024 byte blocks, my du also uses 1024 byte block, stat uses  512 byte blocks. This is on Fedora 27. This is one reason why blocks can be confusing: depending on who you talk to, they can be almost anything - the only common characteristic is that they are all powers of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls -s` reports the `st_blocks` member of the structure returned by the `stat()`/`lstat()` system calls. That's a number 512-byte blocks. 512 bytes is usually the minimum storage granularity as that corresponds to early disk sectors.

Or at least that's what most `ls` implementations do including the original Unix implementation,  and what POSIX requires.

The GNU implementation of `ls` (also `busybox` which mimics it, both found on Ubuntu) however changed that to 1024-byte blocks, but goes back to 512-byte blocks if the `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` (formerly `$POSIX_ME_HARDER`) variable is in the environment (not for busybox). I suppose that's to make it more readable to a human but that means we lose precision on filesystems that use 512-byte storage granularity and doesn't help with portability.

From the ChangeLog:

> Wed Aug 21 13:03:14 1991  David J. MacKenzie  (djm at wookumz.gnu.ai.mit.edu)
>
> - Version 3.0.
> - du.c, ls.c: Make 1K blocks the default size, and -k a no-op.
>     Down with dumb standards!

With GNU `ls` (not busybox), the block size can also be specified with the `--block-size` option or the `$LS_BLOCK_SIZE` environment variable. So you can use `ls --block-size=1 -s` or `LS_BLOCK_SIZE=1 ls -s` to get the disk usage in bytes. Other `ls` implementations like on BSDs use `$BLOCKSIZE` for that¹ (also recognised as well as `$BLOCK_SIZE` by GNU `ls` as [shown by @yahol](/a/430734)).

POSIXly, you can use `-k` to get the count in kibibytes (which thankfully with GNU or BSD `ls` takes precedence over the `$BLOCKSIZE` environment variables).

Portably (if you want to take into account busybox `ls` where, the report in kibibytes is hard coded), to get back to the `st_blocks` (or at least an approximation thereof), you'd need something like:

```
blocks=$(ls -skd -- "$file" | awk '{print $1*2; exit}')
```

With GNU `find`, `-printf %b` reports a number of 512-byte blocks, and `-printf %k` 1024-byte blocks, and it's not affected by the environment. `-printf` is GNU specific.

In any case, nowadays, that has nothing to do with the filesystem block size.

---

<sup>¹ On BSDs, `$BLOCKSIZE` is rounded to a multiple of 512 (`BLOCKSIZE=1023` is the same `BLOCKSIZE=512`) and values below 512 are not allowed</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in `info coreutils Block size` (to which I found my way from `info ls`):

```
2.3 Block size

(...)The block size used for display is independent of
any file system block size.(...)

‘DF_BLOCK_SIZE’
     This specifies the default block size for the ‘df’ command.
     Similarly, ‘DU_BLOCK_SIZE’ specifies the default for ‘du’ and
     ‘LS_BLOCK_SIZE’ for ‘ls’.
```

Seems, that each of these programs can use different block size defined in environmental variables.

The following two `env` variables can help unify the output:

```
‘BLOCK_SIZE’
     This specifies the default block size for all three commands, if
     the above command-specific environment variables are not set.

‘BLOCKSIZE’
     This specifies the default block size for all values that are
     normally printed as blocks, if neither ‘BLOCK_SIZE’ nor the above
     command-specific environment variables are set.  Unlike the other
     environment variables, ‘BLOCKSIZE’ does not affect values that are
     normally printed as byte counts, e.g., the file sizes contained in
     ‘ls -l’ output.
```

And this explains where it all defaults to 512 blocks:

```
‘POSIXLY_CORRECT’
     If neither ‘COMMAND_BLOCK_SIZE’, nor ‘BLOCK_SIZE’, nor ‘BLOCKSIZE’
     is set, but this variable is set, the block size defaults to 512.
```